Lizmap plugin : action error The answer does not include QGIS Server in JSON document
I previously asked Installation of Lizmap Debian : error with QGIS Server in the action part of the Lizmap plugin and still need your help.
I now understand that QGIS Server is the server and that Lizmap is the client (progress..).
We do have a working QGIS Server and have tested serving maps with it, it is ok.
However what I do not understand is on the Lizmap side.
On the Lizmap web client administration part I understand that you put the link of the repository with your QGIS project and other files (ie png for thumbnail, and configuration files generated by Lizmap.
The problem in using the Lizmap plugin within QGIS where :

we managed to connect to the server, but then have a problem hightlighted in red in the action column saying The answer does not include QGIS Server in the JSON document (what does that mean ?)
and then when trying to publish the map (ie generating the configuration file I suppose) nothing happens when clicking the only and main button, so I still need your help.


Sorry, but the answer is the same as in your previous question Installation of Lizmap Debian : error with QGIS Server in the action part of the Lizmap plugin

The answer does not include QGIS Server in the JSON document


We don't know which URL you used, so difficult to answer you. But you should add the URL of the Lizmap Web Client, the one you have in your webbrowser. The URL is written in your administration panel as well.

As written in the screenshot when the plugin asks you the URL, visit your administration panel, then "Server information" (Information serveur in French)

